# Do Shia have narration of mubahala between Moses and Qaroon?

Tags: hadith, shiism, prophet-musa

Stories of the Prophet by ibn Kathir mentions mubahala on page 440 (darrussalam edition) between Moses and Qaroon. Note: Mohahala means cursing each other.

Do Shias have similar narration in their books?

Comment: Does it also mention why did one messenger curse another messenger? Is there also any backings from Qur'an quoted by Ibn Khatir about their story?

Comment: @Honey What are you talking about? Qaroon was not a messenger.

Answer (score 1):

```
             In the name of Allah, the most compassionate, the most merciful.
```

As much as I have done a mediocre research, **there doesn't seem to be such narration of Mubahala between Moses and Qaroon according to Shia Hadiths (Islamic narrations)**, but the hadith of Mubahala which have been mentioned is relevant to the Prophet (peace be upon him and his family) and the Christians of Najran, which is as follows:

> Thus, the Prophet (s) suggested Christians of Najran to do mubahala
>   and they accepted; however, on the day they had agreed before, they
>   refused to do mubahala since they saw that the Prophet (s) came with
>   closest members of his family, who were his daughter Fatima al-Zahra
>   (a), his son-in-law Imam 'Ali (a), his grandsons Hasan (a) and Husayn
>   (a) and thus they understood his truthfulness. This way the Prophet
>   (s) became victorious in this event.

**Reference:**
fa.wikishia.net/view/مباهله

Comment: Doesnt answer the question

Comment: Dear Preordainment, as much as I see, the questioner asks: if Shia have (or not), so, clearly my answer is about if it is or not. Good luck.